# Поиск слова в файле

Tags: python, поиск, файлы

Есть файл `.txt` . В нем записан текст. Нужно создать сигнатуру с информацией (например a='привет') и проверить, есть ли эта сигнатура в файле. Если да - то вывести на экран ее.

Comment: а на каком языке программирования это вам нужно?

Comment: А тривиально вызвать `grep`?

Comment: @Rumato, наверное, на ассемблере )))

Comment: На питоне господа, забыл, что это сайт не только для питона)

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы напечатать все строки, которые содержат заданное слово в данном текстовом файле, закодированном в utf-8 кодировке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import io

word = u'привет'
with io.open('/path/to/file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if word in line:
            print(line, end='')
```

- данный метод закрывает входной файл (`with`-инструкция), не рассчитывая на особенности уборки мусора в реализации интерпретатора или возникновения исключений (ошибок)
- считывание файла идёт построчно без загрузки всего файла в память
- поддерживаются произвольные Юникодные символы (можно другую кодировку использовать в `io.open()` вызове -- она никак не связана с кодировкой исходного кода)
- один и тот же код работает как на Питоне 2 так и на Питоне 3.

Answer (score 3):

создадим переменную с искомым словом:

```
w = 'слово'
```

открываем нужный файл для чтения (при необходимости указываем полный путь к файлу):

```
f = open('test.txt')
```

читаем из файла текст и присваиваем его переменной:

```
text = f.read()
```

закрываем прочтенный файл:

```
f.close()
```

сохраняем кол-во вхождений слова в тексте:

```
c = text.count(w)
```

выводим слово столько раз, сколько оно присутствует в тексте:

```
while c > 0:
    print(w)
    c -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Наверное как-то так.

```
a='Hello'
file=open('/path/to/file/text.txt','r')
text=file.read()
if a in text:
    print a
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать index = text.find("искомый текст"). Даст позицию начала искомой фразы. Но такой метод дает самое первое вхождение искомой фразы. Но ведь одинаковых искомых фраз в тексте может быть несколько. Здесь вам, очевидно, стоит смотреть в сторону регулярных выражений.