# Чтение из одной строки в файле

Tags: python, файлы

Есть файл с содержимым:

```
car cat    машина кошка
```

в массив хочу записать:

```
mas = [['car', 'cat'],['машина','кошка']]
```

Как реализовать такой способ чтения?

Comment: в чём вопрос состоит? (Как [прочитать строку из файла](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413612/23044)? Или как разбить строку на слова ([по пробелам (`str.split()`)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/359110/23044))? Или [как сгруппировать по два слова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/377884/23044)?)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Логика действий: строку разбить на слова

```
s=input()
t=s.split()
```

Дальше поэлементным перебором: первая пара образует один массив, вторая пара - второй, эти оба массива объединить в результирующий mas

Второй вариант сортировки ( не указано в вопросе) - определение кириллицы и латиницы, гугл  в помощь.